# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a newer to tensorflow, I really don't know how to solve the problem.

The code is like:

1. Feed the train with values:

   ```
   sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={images: e, labels: l, keep_prob_fc2: 0.5})
   ```
2. Use the value in CNN:

   ```
   x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10 * 1024])
   ```

Then have the error

> ```
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
>      [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
> ```

I print the input valuetypes using `print(e.dtype)` and the result is `float32` and `e.shape:(10, 32, 32, 1)`.

I really don't know why this error is happening.

---

The code format

First:

```
 define the CNN model 
       "image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [FLAGS.batch_size, 32,32,1])" is here
```

Second:

```
 loss funtion and train_op is here
       "label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, FLAGS.batch_size])" is here
```

Third is the session:

```
images, labels = getShuffleimage()#here will get shuffle data
num_examples = 0
init = tf.initialize_local_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Start populating the filename queue.
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

    try:
        step = 0
        while not coord.should_stop():
            start_time = time.time()
            image, label = sess.run([images, labels])#get shuffle images
            print(image.shape)
            print(image.dtype)
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={image: image, label: label , keep_prob_fc2: 0.5})
            duration = time.time() - start_time

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('Done training after reading all data')
    finally:
        # When done, ask the threads to stop.
        coord.request_stop()

        # Wait for threads to finish.
        coord.join(threads)
        sess.close()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some questions

first
why you use `sess = tf.InteractiveSession()` and `with tf.Session() as sess:` at same time, just curious

second
what is your placeholder name `x` or `images`?
if name is `x`, `{images: x_data...}` won't feed `x_data` to `x`, it override(?) `images`
I think feed_dict should be `{x: x_data...}`

if name is `images`,do you have two `images` in your program, `placeholder` and `shuffle data`, try to modify name of variable

Comment: First, my bach_size is 10, imagesize is 32*32*1,  so I replace the placeholder to: x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10, 1024]) ,Second, g is also used in train_op. But, the error is the same

Comment: shape of input image is 1D or 3D? if the shape is 3D, your shape of placeholder should be something like `[None, 32, 32, 1]`. 
If shape is 1D, the `key` of feed_dict and name of `placeholder` should be same.
your feed_dict is `{images: e ...}`, so there is a `placeholder` named images

Comment: i have convert the image to 3D, and shuffle them to baches. "e" is one of the batch_output, it's shape is [10,32,32,1],and type is "float32". I feed "e" into train. x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10,32,32,1] is used to get data, but get the error "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [10,32,32,1]"

Comment: do you run `sess.run` before `x = tf.place....`? define model first and then `sess.run` or can you paste more precise code?

Comment: All parameters are sync  as your suggested, shown in question updated. But I get another error: "unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'",need your help?

Comment: Thank you very mucn , I have solved it .The reason is as you say, feed_dict I use a wrong name.

Answer (score 2):

I saw one problem with the code. There are two variables with the same name `label`. One of them refers to a Tensor, and the other one refers to some data. When you set `label: label` in the `feed_dict`, you need to distinguish between the two variables.
Maybe you can try changing the name for one of the variables?